# Regex to find anchor tag not working accurately

Tags: php, regex

I have the following regex to find anchor tag that has 'Kontakt' as the anchor text:

```
#<a.*href="[^"]*".*>Kontakt<\/a>#
```

Here is the string to find from:

```
<li class="item-133"><a href="/webdesign-tipps" title="Wissenswertes zu Webdesign, Grafikdesign oder Onlinemarketing">Wissenswertes</a></li><li class="item-115"><a href="/webagentur" >Webagentur</a></li><li class="item-257"><a href="/team" >Team</a></li><li class="item-116 menu-parent"><a href="/support" >Support<span class="menu-toggler"></span></a></li><li class="item-350"><a href="/jobs" >Jobs</a></li><li class="item-120"><a href="/kontakt" >Kontakt</a></li></ul>
```

So the result should be:

```
<a href="/kontakt" >Kontakt</a>
```

But the result I get is:

```
<a href="/webdesign-tipps" title="Wissenswertes zu Webdesign, Grafikdesign oder Onlinemarketing">Wissenswertes</a></li><li class="item-115"><a href="/webagentur" >Webagentur</a></li><li class="item-257"><a href="/team" >Team</a></li><li class="item-116 menu-parent"><a href="/support" >Support<span class="menu-toggler"></span></a></li><li class="item-350"><a href="/jobs" >Jobs</a></li><li class="item-120"><a href="/kontakt" >Kontakt</a>
```

And here is my PHP code:

```
$pattern = '#<a.*href="[^"]*".*>Kontakt<\/a>#';
preg_match_all($pattern, $string, $matches);
```

Comment: Do you know that your html string is invalid html?  Why not parse the html with a legitimate html parser?  Regex is "DOM-ignorant".  `.*` is greedily matching any character (twice in the pattern).

Answer (score 1):

You are using `preg_match_all()` so I assume you are willing to receive multiple qualifying anchor tags.  Parsing valid HTML with a legitimate DOM parser will always be more stable and easier to read than the equivalent regex technique.  It's just not a good idea to rely on regex for DOM parsing because regex is "DOM-unaware" -- it just matches things that *look* like HTML entities.

In the XPath query, search for `<a>` tags (existing at any depth in the document) which have the qualifying string as the whole text.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/m6IX8))

```
$html = <<<HTML
<li class="item-133"><a href="/webdesign-tipps" title="Wissenswertes zu Webdesign, Grafikdesign oder Onlinemarketing">Wissenswertes</a></li><li class="item-115"><a href="/webagentur" >Webagentur</a></li><li class="item-257"><a href="/team" >Team</a></li><li class="item-116 menu-parent"><a href="/support" >Support<span class="menu-toggler"></span></a></li><li class="item-350"><a href="/jobs" >Jobs</a></li><li class="item-120"><a href="/kontakt" >Kontakt</a></li></ul>
HTML;

$dom = new DOMDocument;
libxml_use_internal_errors(true);
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$result = [];
foreach ($xpath->query('//a[text() = "Kontakt"]') as $a) {
    $result[] = $dom->saveHtml($a);
}
var_export($result);
```

Output:

```
array (
  0 => '<a href="/kontakt">Kontakt</a>',
)
```

Is it more concise to use regex? Yes, but it is also less reliable for general use.

You will notice that the DOMDocument also automatically cleans up the unnecessary spacing in your markup.

Comment: 100% avoid regex whenever possible. Great answer.

Comment: I phrase my personal philosophy of when to use regex slightly differently.  "Only use regex when it provides a valuable advantage over other techniques."  The "what is valuable" is largely subjective.  I find myself electing to use one regex function call instead of two non-regex function calls as a matter of directness -- even if the two function calls might be nanoseconds faster. Opinions vary.  My stance about parsing valid HTML with regex is far less flexible.

Answer (score 0):

If you can trust your input will always have `<a href` in every anchor tag then try:

```php
'#<a href="[^"]*"[^>]*>Kontakt<\/a>#';

// Instead of what you have:

'#<a.*href="[^"]*".*>Kontakt<\/a>/#';
```

`.*` is the "wildcard" meta-character `.` and the "zero or more times" quantifier `*` together.

`.*` matches anything any number of times.

Try it https://regex101.com/r/qxnRZv/1

Answer (score -1):

Your regex:

`...a.*href...`

is greedy, which means: "after a, match as many characters as possible before a href". That causes your regex to return multiple hrefs.

You can use the lazy-mode operator `?` :

`...a.*?href....`

which means "after a, match as few characters as possible before a href". It should work.

Comment: Even if you use lazy matching, the regex engine will do whatever it can to "make a match" -- this will lead to incorrect results.

Comment: Proof: https://3v4l.org/83Lds